# S3 presigned url: 403 error when reading a file but OK when downloading

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am working with a s3 presigned url.
OK: links works well to download.
NOT OK: using the presigned url to read a file in the bucket

I am getting the following error in console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code><Message>Query-string authentication version 4 requires the X-Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential, X-Amz-Signature, X-Amz-Date, X-Amz-SignedHeaders, and X-Amz-Expires parameters.</Message>
```

and here is how generate the url with `boto3`

```
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'), region_name='eu-west-3')
    bucket_name = config("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")

    file_name = '{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(user, 'projects', building.building_id, file.file)

    ifc_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
        'get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': bucket_name,
            'Key': file_name,
        },
        ExpiresIn=1799
    )
```

I am using IFC.js which allows to load ifc formated models from their urls . Basically the url of the bucket acts as the path to the file. Accessing files in a public bucket has been working well however it won't work with private buckets.

Something to note as well is that using the presigned url copied from clipboard from the aws s3 interface works.
it looks like this:

```
"https://bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/om1/projects/1/v1.ifc?response-content-disposition=inline&X-Amz-Security-Token=qqqqzdfffrA%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230105T224241Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Credential=5%2Feu-west-3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=c470c72b3abfb99"
```

the one I obtain with boto3 is the following:

```
"https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/om1/projects/1/v1.ifc?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKI230105%2Feu-west-3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230105T223404Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=1b4f277b85639b408a9ee16e"
```

I am fairly new to use s3 buckets so I am not sure what is wrong here, and searching around on SO and online has not been very helpful so far. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: To read the file you have to download the file. So not sure what do you mean that it does not work for reading. Please explain.

Comment: I have been able to read file without needing to download. The bucket path acts as the path to the file. In my case I use a js library that loads models from their url and it reads s3 files just fine when the bucket is public. Right now I am trying to do the same with a private s3 bucket and a presigned url to access the object.

Comment: I have updated my post to add clarity @Marcin

Comment: How are you attempting to use the URL?  Please post a [mre] of the failure, as it is now, you appear to be generating a valid URL, but however it's being used might be the issue.